# Has anybody discovered a (simple) way to limit group_concat rows?

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat, concatenation

I have a pretty big query to pull out the information about reports from each country, and right now, the only way I can limit this is by putting `Limit 10` or some number at the end, which will limit the countries. However, what I want to do is limit the `group_concat` to 10 results per country, which in my case would be somehow limiting 10 to each instance of the word `group_concat`.

My current query is:

```
SELECT country,
GROUP_CONCAT(docID),
GROUP_CONCAT(analyst),
GROUP_CONCAT(region),
GROUP_CONCAT(report),
GROUP_CONCAT(topic),
MAX((date)) AS date,
MAX((docID)) AS docID,
GROUP_CONCAT(date) AS dates,
GROUP_CONCAT(event) AS events,
GROUP_CONCAT(province) AS provinces
FROM reports GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY date DESC, docID DESC
```

I have seen this question asked, and I haven't seen any really good answers. I know the function is not built into MySQL, as you can only limit based on the characters. Has anybody solved this problem before?

Comment: I think you have to do a "top N per group" query and apply group_concat to its result.

Comment: Whoa that could be a lot of extra code to write. Gonna mess with it for a sec.

Comment: Gah... don't use repeated string concatenation. Makes the query hard to read. Use a heredoc (php.net/heredoc) instead so you can have "pure" sql surrounded by a bit of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Workaround**
One options is to pad your values with <strike>spaces</strike>`#`. So every item in group_concat is the same length.
Lets suppose there are no items longer than 20 chars.

Then your query would be:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 10*20+9; /*execute this first.*/
/*10 items, 20 bytes each + 9 bytes for the separator*/

SELECT country,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),docID),20)),'#','') AS docIDs, 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),analyst),20)),'#','') AS analysts, 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),region,20)),'#','') AS regions, 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),report,20)),'#','') AS reports, 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),topic,20)),'#','') AS topics, 
MAX((date)) AS `date`,  /* LATEST DATE*/
MAX((docID)) AS docID,  /* LATEST DOC*/
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),date,20)),'#','') AS dates, 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),event,20)),'#','') AS events, 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT(repeat('#',20),province,20)),'#','') AS provinces 
FROM reports 
GROUP BY country ORDER BY `date` DESC, docID DESC
```

Just to recap:

```
x= CONCAT(repeat('#',20),docID)  adds 20 x #################### in front of docID
y= RIGHT(X,20)                   Takes the rightmost 20 chars of that
z= GROUP_CONCAT(y)               strings these together up to max_len
result = REPLACE(z,'#','') removes the `#` so the result looks normal.
```

**Or write your own version of group_concat**
You can use your own group_concat UDF.
There are a couple of examples floating around on the net.

E.g.: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mygroupconcat.aspx?display=Mobile

Comment: @RVWard, because you are not showing **all** values of `group_concat` you may consider changing the statement to `group_concat(x order by `date` desc, docID desc) or you might get unexpected results. `Group_concat` needs it's own order clause you see.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of my example to limit posts per users

```
select user_id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(posts.id order by rand()),',',3) from posts inner join users on users.id = posts.user_id group by posts.user_id;
```